# Running a set of commands from a batch file (run VSCode, run NG serve)

Tags: angular, batch-file, visual-studio-code

OK, so I want to run my whole working environment from a batch file...

what I would like to achieve...

1. Open new powershell, open my API folder and run VS Code editor from that folder (cd c:\xy; code .)
2. Run API express server (node .)
3. Open new powershell, Change dir to my angular cli app and run the vscode there (cd c:\xy-app; code .)
4. Run ng serve
5. open chrome on http://localhost:4200 after ng serve is done

Hope it makes sense...
I tried this in my run-work.bat

```
cd C:\xy
code .
node .
cd C:\xy-app
code .
ng serve
```

it stops after running the first `code .` so the `node .` does not get executed

any ideas?

I want to run all commands listed in succession! Possibly terminating in 5 windows open.... powershell 1 (with node server running) powershell 2 (with angular app running) vscode 1 (with API app), vscode 2 (with Angular app) and a chrome window

Comment: you want to have a batch file and clicking on it should open `vs-code` `launch the app` etc? correct?

Comment: No, I want to run all commands listed in succession! Possibly terminating in 5 windows open.... powershell 1 (with node server running) powershell 2 (with angular app running) vscode 1 (with API app), vscode 2 (with Angular app) and a chrome window

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
start /min cmd /c "cd C:\{path to angular project} && code . && ng serve --port 4200 --open"
start /min cmd /c "cd C:\{path to express project} && code . && npm run dev"
```

/min to open cmd minimized. This will open 4 windows i.e a cmd with angular app, a cmd with node server, a vs code with angular app and a vs code with api app.

`--open` after `ng serve` with open browser after it has finished building.

Answer (score 2):

Save this in a bat file

```
d:
cd ......
code && npm start
```

In your `package.json` specify `-o` to automatically launch in browser as below

```
  "start": "ng serve -o -w",
```

Comment: so need more help?

Comment: yeah... I would like to have two apps running... not only one (with two editors)

Comment: the other app can be called here as well `code && npm start  && devenv` in case of visual studio

Comment: but I would like to windows opened... where I can see the logs from both apps

Comment: windows as in? I m not getting you

Comment: two powershell console windows

Comment: `cd C:\xy
code . && node .
cd C:\xy-app
code . && ng serve`

stops after running the node . (coz it's listening)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
echo  Welcome to Electrofixes

pause 
cd C:\Users\skshr\Desktop\medical_science 
ng serve --port 4200 --open
pause
```

---

Comment: Please explain your code, and why it is relevant, since other answers were provided and it is 1 year old question.